# Rails Delete not working in namespacing with the Confirm Are You Sure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using `rails 6.1.4` and `ruby 3.1.1`

In my app I have a students model in a sub-directory: `living_muay_thai/students`.  I'm having problems trying to figure out how to delete students with the `link_to` and `Confirm - Are you sure?`.  The same delete code works outside of the sub-directory, so I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong with the namespacing in the `link_to`.  Currently it is taking me to the `show` view. I believe it uses the same route as `show`, but I thought by adding `method: :delete` it would go to the destroy action in the controller. What am I missing?

```rb
# controller

def destroy
    @student = LivingMuayThai::Student.find(params[:id])
    @student.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "#{@student.fname} #{@student.lname} has been deleted."                                                           
    redirect_to(action: "index")
  end
```

```html
# view

<% @students.each do |s| %>
    <tr>
        <td class="border-right"><%= s.fname %></td>
        <td class="border-right"><%= s.lname %></td>
        <td class="border-right"><%= link_to("Show", living_muay_thai_student_url(s.id), action: :show) %></td>
        <td class="border-right"><%= link_to("Edit", edit_living_muay_thai_student_url(s.id)) %></td>
        <td class="border-right">
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', living_muay_thai_student_url(s.id), method: :delete, 
                                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

I originally had this: `<%= link_to 'Destroy', s, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`   This also would take me to the `show` view.  I've tried a couple other things, but nothing is working.

Since the delete (with `Confirm: Are you sure`) works in the rest of the app (outside of the namespacing), "I think" the  JQuery is working inside the namespacing.

I'm hoping someone can point out the errors of my ways on this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In the HTML produced in your browser, do you see the `data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?"`

Comment: *JQuery is working*, rails-ujs probably you mean. Check that you have correct script tag in the final HTML on that page

Answer (score 0):

@smathy, @mechnicov

Thanks for the posts.  It got me thinking.  I compared the layout files for my main application and the sub-directory.  These were missing in the sub-directory layout. I added them and viola, it worked.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: Heh, you had different layouts :)